# How does the predicate i/4 function in Prolog

Tags: nlp, prolog

In "Representation and Inference for Natural Language - A First Course in Computational Semantics"  by Blackburn and Bos  they introduce the predicate i/4:

```
i(X,model(_,F),G,Value):-
    (
       var(X),
       memberList(g(Y,Value),G),
       Y==X, ! % IMPORTANT CUT!
    ;
      atom(X),
      memberList(f(0,X,Value),F)
    ).
```

They briefly mentioned that the predicate i/4  interprets terms using the variable
assignment `g`, if the term  is a variable, and with the interpretation function `F`,
if it is a constant, but they do not address  the "IMPORTANT CUT!" comment.

I don't understand what the funtion `G` represents and I also don't fully understand the importance of the line `Y==X, !`

I tried to run the  code without the line `Y==X, !`,to figure out what it does,  but it just gives me an error.

I also know that `Y==X` returns either 0 (when X != Y) or 1 (when X = Y),but I don't don't know what the `, !` part is supposed to mean.

Comment: A _cut_ (`!`) is a stop of evaluation. You might read it as `if Y equals X then halt else (`;`) ,,, The comma (`,`) meaning _and then_ and the semicolon (`;`) for the alternative, _or else_.

Comment: A better comment than "IMPORTANT CUT!" would be: "Prevent backtracking into memberList because only 1 success is needed".
Prolog has a built-in inference engine, which is hugely useful, and greatly confuses imperative-language programmers.